# iOS: Storing and triggering a callback block

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, callback, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to find out if there is a standard way of storing a callback block and have it executed later without the use of storing the block in a property or dictionary.

**Imagine the following scenario:**

I have a class, let's say `MyApiClient` and it has a method called `getListOfBooksWithCompletionHandler:(void (^))completion`, where the completion block is called when the request finishes. So good so far.

Internally `MyApiClient` has to call some methods of other APIs that don't offer a completion but blocks, only delegate calls.

This means I need to store the callback block somewhere until the respective delegate method is called from that other API.

In a past project I solved this by storing the callback block in a `NSMutableDictionary` and use some kind of unique identifier to find it during the delegate call.

This feels like unneeded boilerplate code to me though, **so my question is**: Is there a best practice/API to do this more elegantly? Maybe some mechanism that allows me to store the block with a certain ID and simply trigger a signal that will dispatch the call to the block?

Couldn't find much about this using google nor Apple's documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: Why you don't use property to store the block, you can add it to class extension?

Comment: The problem with that is that it would only allow one request at the same time. If the first request didn't finish yet and you trigger a second request, it would overwrite the previous callback handler, leading to lots of problems. As I stated, I worked around this by using a dictionary to store blocks in, but the point of my question is to find out if there is a better way.

Comment: what about using delegates instead of blocks then ?

Comment: Delegates are much more flexible in my project's case, because there is a lot of nested stuff happening. In fact we are migrating away from global NSNotifications and delegates - which results in much cleaner and less complex code.

Comment: Oops, I meant blocks. My fault.

Comment: @badcat: Each request should be done by a *separate instance* of your class. The you can store the completion block as a property without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you store the completion block in a property of your class

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(parameters ...);
```

and create *separate instances* for each request. Then each instance can hold the block
and other state information for one particular request. It can also serve as the delegate
for the "other API" that you are using.

Comment: This won't be suitable because the class has a kind of manager role and exists only once like a singleton (as it manages dependencies and caches). See my comments above.

Comment: @badcat: I have read your comments, but I still think that creating separate instances for each request is the best solution. If you have a single manager than that manger can create instances of a helper class for each request. Having separate delegate objects for your "other API" greatly simplifies things in my opinion.

Comment: @badcat: Perhaps you can give some more information what your manager class does.